# Google safesearch is on for every browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, email, browser, google-search

I have uninstalled chrome multiple times and used other browsers and all of them have google safesearch on.
I noticed safesearch was on when my brother signed into his school email on chrome. Though I have signed out, safesearch is still on.
I only use firefox for my school email and safesearch was on there, but when school email was signed in on chrome it translated to every browser apparently.

I don't know how but I think my school network is changing my safesearch settings. Can they also track everything I access through chrome even if I don't sign into their email? How can I switch off safesearch permanently (through network proxies or some other method)?

[screenshot of my safesearch setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCDDq.png)

Comment: I have just tried with a VPN and safesearch is off... it is probably my school network doing this.

Comment: Its unclear *where* you are having this issue. At school? Then yes, they can disable turning it off at the network level, which explains why using a VPN worked for you. Are you having this issue at home?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how but I think my school network is changing my safesearch settings. Can they also track everything I access through chrome even if I don't sign into their email?

This is only possible because [Google Search allows the network to lock SafeSearch](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/186669?hl=en).  Google Search only allows the network to lock SafeSearch and does not help the network do anything else, including tracking.[*]

Google, and most other websites, use `https://`.  This establishes a secure connection over the network, shown by the padlock in the address bar.  Clicking the padlock will show technical information.

So long as you are on a HTTPS website, the network itself cannot track or change specific *content*, and cannot track specific pages *within* each website.

A DNS redirect can lock SafeSearch, by redirecting to a server which Google has provided for this specific purpose.  If the network redirected `google.com` to a non-Google tracking server, they would not have the right HTTPS certificate to prove ownership of `google.com`, and the browser would show a security error.  The network cannot entirely defeat HTTPS by using DNS redirects.[**]

[*] There is one other network opt-out, but not by Google Search or by Google.  Current Firefox in the US defaults to DNS-over-HTTPS, but allows networks to opt users out of this.  Google Chrome supports DNS-over-HTTPS and has no network opt-out.  Apparently Google Chrome is enabling D-O-H by default on Android phones.

[**] A network could try to defeat HTTPS websites, by only allowing HTTP.  This would be very noticeable, because it would block websites that use HSTS / pinning including `google.com`.  It would also break starting points that use `https://` addresses, including the default search engines in web browsers.)

---

> Q: can I switch off safesearch permanently (through network proxies or some other method)?

Please search responsibly... but I'm genuinely curious whether all the above features interact how I think they do.

> A DNS redirect can lock SafeSearch

> on a HTTPS website, the network itself cannot track or change specific content

> DNS-over-HTTPS